# how to run protractor test from UI or web interface - just select scenario from github and run

Tags: angular, testing, protractor

trying to build a UI where anybody can run protractor tests without having knowledge of JS or scripts..they should have scenarios available to them from the github repo and they just choose which one to run

Comment: is there a way to get list of all tags and scenarios from protractor test suite

Comment: What's the point your are trying to make / what is your question?

Comment: @wswebcreation : point is to make execution easy for protractor test cases. instead of editing conf.js everytime to specify which tags you want to run, use the UI to select tags that you want to run

Answer (score 0):

For this, you don't need to build a UI from scratch. What you need to setup is a Continous Integration Envrionment like [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/). Then you can create "**Jobs**" that contain choice parameters for running different tests.

Here is an example of one of my Jenkins Jobs for running the core suite of my tests with different options that I created and all get passed to Protractor. [image]